# Fast approximation of $\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-\beta \ln(i)+\gamma{\ln}^2(i)}$ for large $n$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I need a numerical approximation with low computational complexity of

$$\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-\beta \ln(i)+\gamma{\ln}^2(i)}$$  for $n\approx10^6$, where $1\lt\beta\lt3$ and $0<\gamma<0.05$

I have unsuccessfully (and naively) tried to use the Euler–Maclaurin formula.
Would anyone have a suggestion ?

Comment: Set $a_i =e^{-\beta\ln(i)+\gamma \ln^2(i)}$, if I'm not wrong $$a_1+...+a_n$$ increases extremely rapid to infinity and $$\frac{ a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{a_n}$$ converges to a constant that can be calculated explicitly (1 if I'm not wrong again). So I'm not sure how will approximate your value.

Comment: Anyways, your question doesn't meet the quality standards of MSE. I think you would need to add more context(for example, "Why do you think such approximation exists?")  to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Here I am not looking for an asymptotic approximation, but for a computationaly efficient way to calculate the expression for various values of $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $n$ in the indicated ranges

Comment: Have you tried Cross-Validation exchange? Your computational question is likely more oriented to that stackexchange rather than MSE.

Comment: Have you tried direct summation of the first $m$ terms and using Euler-Maclaurin for the rest? Have you used the remainder term in some form?